# Is this P trap and AAV configuration acceptable with regard to the dishwasher drain inlet?

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

Our new sink arrived and the position of the drain from the wall is higher than ideal.  Because of this, I ordered a reversible P trap to accommodate the drain location elevation and also intend to install an AAV since there is no vent.  Are there any potential issues with this current configuration of the P trap in general or due to the location of the dishwasher drain fitting on the tail piece and does the AAV configuration appear to pose no issue ?

See photos:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/pLGtiyq1nrGgfxTN9

https://photos.app.goo.gl/yuUJLNY1GJyJsGVo7

Comment: Aside from not being plumbing-code-compliant (having trap seal > 4"), I wouldn't be surprised if DW discharge backed up into the sink above to some degree. Most AAV's specify installation 4" or more above trap arm, so you may be good there. Your install could also work just fine.